# OpenCL: call to a built-in function is ambiguous

Tags: c, opencl

I have a following piece of code which is from a openCL kernel.

```
     const uint idz = 100;
     const uint idy = 100;
     unit4 size_sino;
     uint idz_p;
     uint idy_p;
     idz_p = (idz*size_sino.y+idy)/16;
     idy_p = fmod((idz*size_sino.y+idy), (uint)16);
```

When I compiled the kernel, some error happened:

```
     :192:18: error: call to 'fmod' is ambiguous
     <stdin>:1078:48: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1084:49: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1079:49: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1080:49: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1081:49: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1082:49: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1083:50: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1085:50: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1086:50: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1087:50: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1088:50: note: candidate function
     <stdin>:1089:51: note: candidate function
```

fmod() is a built-in function which has been overloaded. I understand the type of the two inputs should be the same. Could anyone tell what's going on here?

Comment: You should probably provide more code, e.g. how is the fmod overload declared.

Comment: What is the type of `unit4` ? Is it a floating point value or an integer ?

Comment: @zenith it's a built-in OpenCL function

Comment: @chmike it's type of vector composites from 4 uint type, size_sino.y is one     unit of those 4

Comment: @colddie I know, I just think it wasn't that clear. You could attach its prototype to your question so people wouldn't have to go googling around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are calling `fmod` with two `uint` arguments. This function has overloads for `float` and `double` arguments, and so the compiler cannot infer which overload you wish to use (hence the error about the ambiguous function call).

You can make your intentions explicit by casting the arguments to the type that you want to use:

```
idy_p = fmod((float)(idz*size_sino.y+idy), (float)16.f);
```